# Regex Scipt needed to remove a character pattern in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have horse names which I wish to alter by removing the letters NZ from the end of the name.

eg HARRY NZ needs to be altered to HARRY.

This NZ does not always appear at the end of the name.

I am a complete novice so I will need the exact regex entries or C# entries so I can copy and paste.

Comment: If you only want copy-paste answers you'll always be a complete novice.

Comment: I'm not sure why people vote this down. If I were a complete novice, I'd likely have questions like this. Searching only gets one so far when one doesn't know what to search for. It's not a question that deserves up votes but it shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: -1 To quote the down arrow tooltip "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: @SaintGerbil It also shows "unclear or not useful" which - in my opinion - don't apply. The poster did mention regex so he obviously did _some_ research but he said he's a novice so he may not know what to do with that. Downvoting novices on novice questions discourages them from learning more.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always just `_NZ`, you don't really need a regex to remove it from names, you can do

```
name = name.Replace ( " NZ", String.Empty );
```

The [`String.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) function will simply blindly replace `_NZ` with a 0-length string, effectively removing `_NZ` from the name. This assumes that `_NZ` can always be replaced in any name, regardless of its position within the name.

If there's some rule as to when `NZ` can be removed then you'll need a regex but then you need to specify about those rules.

(Underscore stands for space above.)

Comment: Thankyou xxbbcc, I appreciate your response and help